# which encryption algorithm do serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b'mypassword') use in python cryptography lib?

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I found this code snippet, here it is serializing an RSA private key into an encrypted cipher text. I wanted to know which algorithm in this code `serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b'mypassword')` will be used to do so.

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
pem = private_key.private_bytes(
      encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
      format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
      encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b'mypassword')
)
```

Comment: The only place I see that class being interpreted by the code is [here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/aece5b3d47282beed31f7119e273b65816a0cf93/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py#L1781), where the openssl backend picks `aes-256-cbc` as the cypher to use. I'm not sure I understand the structure of the crypto library to be certain that's the answer you want though.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the comment. Yes, I thinks that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the implementation of the `private_key` object. The `BestAvailableEncryption` just says that you don't have a specific preference and would like the library to pick an encryption type for the key for you.

In the OpenSSL backend (which is the only one, it seems), the best encryption is chosen [here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/aece5b3d47282beed31f7119e273b65816a0cf93/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py#L1781), where it currently selects the `'aes-256-cbc'` cypher. That may change in future versions. Leaving the choice up to the implementation is the reason to have the `BestAvailableEncryption` class.